# Unknown action : Counter not incrementing with Vuex (VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using the following code to increment a counter in store.js using Vuex. Don't know why, when I click the increment button, it says:

> [vuex] unknown action type: INCREMENT

**store.js**

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(Vuex)
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    INCREMENT (state) {
      state.counter++;
    }
  }
})
export default store
```

**IcrementButton.vue**

```
<template>
  <button @click.prevent="activate">+1</button>
</template>

<script>
import store from '../store'

export default {
  methods: {
    activate () {
      store.dispatch('INCREMENT');
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `commit` in the methods as you are triggering a [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html), not an [action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html):

```
export default {
  methods: {
    activate () {
      store.commit('INCREMENT');
    }
  }
}
```

Actions are similar to mutations, the difference being that:

- Instead of mutating the state, actions commit mutations.
- Actions can
  contain arbitrary asynchronous operations.

Comment: @Great! Thanks. That worked. What is the difference between mutations and actions? Writing code like above is ok?

Comment: @GijoVarghese Added in the answer